# Hover over system Tray and open a balloon in Java

Tags: java, system-tray

How do I hover over the system Tray and open a balloon in Java ? I 'am able to open a tool tip , but not able to open a balloon .

However, I can right click on the icon and do a actionPerformed and do this to open a balloon

`trayIcon.displayMessage(title, message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always emulate tooltip behavior yourself with a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener:

```
String message = "Application running";

int hoverTime = 1000;
Timer messageTimer = new Timer(hoverTime,
    e -> trayIcon.displayMessage(null, message,
        TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO));
messageTimer.setRepeats(false);

trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        messageTimer.restart();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        messageTimer.stop();
    }
});
trayIcon.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        messageTimer.restart();
    }
});
```

Note that `Timer` is a javax.swing.Timer, not a java.util.Timer, as the former guarantees its action will be executed in the AWT event dispatch thread.